# Select data from 2 different tables on basis of maximum orders

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I need to select the data from 2 different tables, products and orders, orders table have the productid as a foreign key

### What I need

I need a query that shows some columns from product table, depending upon the maximum number of orders in order table

### My effort

I have tried the following query

```
select sc_products.id, sc_products.name from sc_products, sc_orders where sc_orders.product = sc_products.id
```

### Problem

This query is just returning me the data with duplicating the ids from product table
as

```
Full Texts          id  name
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  10  Black-White Cats
    Edit    Delete  10  Black-White Cats
    Edit    Delete  4   Aquarius Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  4   Aquarius Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  249     Volleyball Mom Blue Rhinestone T Shirt
    Edit    Delete  249     Volleyball Mom Blue Rhinestone T Shirt
```

The above result is shown after my query, I need to show only those records that are ordered multiple times and I need that `count`

### More on what I need

I need a result like following

```
                            id  name                                        count
        Edit    Delete  9   3 Gold-Silver Elephants Rhinestone T Shirt   10
        Edit    Delete  10  product 2                                    15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, COUNT(o.id) orderCnt
FROM sc_products p 
INNER JOIN sc_orders o ON o.product = p.id
GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT(o.id) > 1
ORDER BY orderCnt DESC
```

Comment: unknown column 's' in ON clause

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you need to use the aggregation function COUNT.

We provide a GROUP BY to ensure the counting only ever occurs over unique product entries.  NOTE: scp.id is enough to satisfy this, but all non-aggregated columns must be included in the GROUP BY.

Finally, we use HAVING to limit the results to just those records that have multiple orders (i.e. have a count > 1).

```
SELECT scp.id, scp.name, COUNT(sco.product)
FROM sc_products scp
INNER JOIN sc_orders sco ON scp.id = sco.product
GROUP BY scp.id, scp.name
HAVING COUNT(sco.product) > 1;
```

Comment: when i put `ORDER BY COUNT(sco.product)` in query, it agains shows duplicate results :(

Comment: `SELECT scp.id, scp.name, COUNT(sco.product)
FROM sc_products scp
INNER JOIN sc_orders sco ON scp.id = sco.product
GROUP BY scp.id, scp.name
HAVING COUNT(sco.product) > 1
order by COUNT(sco.product);` i was running

Comment: Very strange.  If I run that same query, I don't get any duplicate results.  Anyway, I'm glad you got it figured out.